# Are all isomorphic simply transitive subgroups of $S_n$ conjugate?

Tags: group-theory

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ letters. Suppose $G,G'\le S_n$ are transitive subgroups of order $n$ such that $G\cong G'$. Must they be conjugate in $S_n$?

My guess is that the answer is either yes, or if not then there should be exactly two conjugacy classes of simply transitive subgroups (represented by the left regular and the right regular representations), but I don't have a proof.

Comment: @Arthur No - the left regular representation of any group of order $n$ is also transitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If a group $G$ of order $n$ acts on a set $X$ of size $n$ transitively, then the stabilizer must be trivial, so $X$ must be isomorphic to the left regular representation of $G$. In particular there is a unique isomorphism class of such action, so any two such actions on $X$ must be conjugate.

(The left and right regular representations are isomorphic, if by the right regular representation you mean $\rho(g) x = xg^{-1}$. The isomorphism sends $x$ to $x^{-1}$.)

Comment: Okay, so here's the statement that one should verify: If $G$ acts simply transitively on the sets $X,Y$ then if you pick $x\in X, y\in Y$, the map $f_{x,y} : X\rightarrow Y$ sending $gx\mapsto gy$ is $G$-equivariant. If $X = Y$, with $G$-actions giving rise to subgroups $G',G''\subset S_X$, then conjugating by $f_{x,y}$ takes $G'$ to $G''$.

Comment: @stupid_question_bot: yes, that's a clean way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Qiaochu Yuan's answer:

The answer is yes.

To see this, one should check the following statements: If $G$ acts simply transitively on sets $X$ and $Y$ then for any $x\in X, y\in Y$, the map $f_{x,y} : X\rightarrow Y$ sending $gx\mapsto gy$ for every $g\in G$ is $G$-equivariant. If $X = Y$, suppose the $G$-actions on $X,Y$ give rise to subgroups $G',G''\subset S_X$, then conjugating by $f_{x,y}$ takes $G'$ to $G''$.