Inverse Galois Theory - Normal polynomials with given Galois group G but with in-equivalent actions on their roots
I am looking for an example of 2 irreducible normal polynomials $f(x), g(x) \in Q[x]$ which have the same Galois group $G$ over $Q$, but for which the action of $G$ on the roots of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is non-equivalent. In particular, the cycle types of the Galois group actions on the roots should be different. Do such polynomials exist ?
An irreducible polynomial is called normal over $K$ if $K[\theta]$ is a splitting field for $f(x)$ over K for each root $\theta$ of $f(x)$ in an extension field of $K$.
Non-examples:
(i) $f(x)=x^2-2$, $g(x)=x^2-3$. They have the same Galois group $C_2$, but with equivalent actions on their roots.
(ii) Let $f(x)$ be normal, $\alpha$ a root of $f(x)$, $\beta=h(\alpha)$ such that $K[\beta]=K[\alpha]$, and let $g(x)$ be the primitive polynomial of $\beta$. Then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same Galois group with equivalent group actions on their roots.
Non-example (ii) means that for a given field extension the action of the Galois Group is independent of the chosen normal polynomial. The question is essentially if the action is also independent across different extensions, but with isomorphic Galois groups.

Maybe another approach is to ask whether any two isomorphic transitive subgroups of the symmetric group $S_n$ are always conjugate.

That's a great way to reformulate my question. According to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3857552/are-all-isomorphic-simply-transitive-subgroups-of-s-n-conjugate the answer is yes, isomorphic simply-transitive subgroups of S_n are always conjugate. This answers my initial question to the negative: Two such polynomials $f(x), g(x)$ do not exist.

Doesn't the normality requirement force the action of the Galois group $G$ to be equivalent to the Cayley action of $G$ on itself? OTOH, if you only ask about two polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ sharing the same Galois group, then their degrees need not match, making the question rather dull. OTOH2, if you fix the degrees and drop the irreducibility assumption, then $f(x)=(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$ and $g(x)=x^4-10x^2+1$ share the same splitting field (and hence the Galois group), but the action on one set of zeros has non-trivial fixed points whereas the other does not.

(cont'd) I'm aware that my OTOHs above were specifically ruled out. They just naturally(?) occured to me in this context :-)

Indeed, if I drop the requirement of $f(x),g(x)$ to be normal and only require they have the same Galois group, than different degrees of the permutation group can occur.  What happens in case $f(x),g(x)$  are irreducible, have the same Galois group and the same degree, but are not normal ? Are then the respective permutation groups of $G$ acting on the roots of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ still conjugate ?

I think the answer to the question in the last comment is No! Think about the outer automorphism $\phi$ of $G=S_6$. It yields two ways for the group $G$ to act on a set of six elements, such that the point stabilizers of one are not conjugate to the point stabilizers of the other, call them $H_1$ and $H_2$ (both are isomorphic to $S_5$, but as subgroups of $S_6$ they are not conjugate). Then if $L/\Bbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $S_6$, and $\theta$ generates a normal basis, then the minimal polynomials $m_i(x)$ of
$$z_i=\sum_{\tau\in H_i}\tau(\theta),$$
$i=1,2$.

Both have degree six (because their conjugates are in bijective correspondence with cosets of $H_i$). Neither of them belongs to the unique normal intermediate field (= the fixed points of the alternating group), so $L$ is the Galois closure of both $\Bbb{Q}(z_1)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(z_2)$. But the actions of the Galois group on the two sets of zeros are not conjugates. For example (if memory serves), there exist automorphisms that act as a single 2-cycle on one set and as a product of three disjoint 2-cycles on the other set.

Of course, in my example all the permutations of the six roots come from a field automorphism in both cases. The point was that cycle structures of the same automorphism look different. Upon rereading, I'm actually not sure that I interpreted that question correctly, either :-)

Thank you, Jyrki. This is exactly the answer I was looking for.
